# ImageMagick is breaking palette of PNG image while cropping/chopping

Tags: colors, imagemagick, palette

I try to crop a PNG image with ImageMagick, but it's breaking the original palette.

My command is:

```
$ convert e11.png -gravity East -chop 70x0 e11-out.png
```

And here is what it does:

Original:

[image: Original]

Chopped:

[image: Chopped]

As you see the pallet is now screwed. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself.

It was a bug in my specific version of ImageMagick: `6.9.11-60`. This version  is the most recent one in the main **Ubuntu 22.04** repository.

However the behavior is correct on ImageMagick `7.1.1`.